# jQuery if object is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a script that copies the text from an image's ALT-text and makes a caption box, and inputs the text.

```
var alt = $("#hoejre p span img").attr("alt");
$('#hoejre p span img').after('<span></span>');
$('#hoejre p span span').html('<strong>' + alt.replace('-', '</strong> <em>') + '</em>');
```

This works great, when there IS an image. But when there aren't any images, the script fails in IE7.

How can I wrap the VAR with an IF sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why call a method when you could just look at length property?

```
if ($imgs.length) {
  ... /* one or more images exist */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can check how many objects a jQuery selector returns with [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/)</strike>

Check **fcalderan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164189/jquery-if-object-is-present/4164258#4164258)**, which suggests using the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property instead.
It has the same result, but is potentially faster.

For example you can do the following:

```
var $imgs = $("#hoejre p span img");
if( $imgs.size() > 0 ) {
    var alt = $imgs.attr("alt"); 
    $('<span></span>').html('<strong>' + alt.replace('-', '</strong> <em>') + '</em>')
                      .insertAfter( $imgs );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The size() method:

```
if ($("#hoejre p span img").size() > 0)
{
  var alt = $("#hoejre p span img").attr("alt");
  $('#hoejre p span img').after('<span></span>');
  $('#hoejre p span span').html('<strong>' + alt.replace('-', '</strong> <em>') + '</em>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors return an array.

You can check whether it contains any elements with the native JS Array.length property. Base your `if` on whether the length is >0.