# Condition if an element present w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table. All cells in a certain row have `<div>`

Some can have a span as well. I need to change the width of the div in a cell is `<span>` is present. How do I check for that?

JS:

```
var divW = $("#myTable td").find("div").width(50);
var spaW = 20;
```

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="tdDiv">abc</div>
    </td><td>
        <div class="tdDiv">abc</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="tdSpan">*</span>
        <div class="tdDiv">abc</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you know how to format code inline in a question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery if object is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164189/jquery-if-object-is-present)

Answer (score 2):

If they're adjacent as shown in the question...

```
$("#myTable td span + div").width(50);
```

Comment: Wow, never though that way. What is the span is not present, it'll just assume that it's 0, right?

Comment: @santa: The selector will only match the `div` element if there's an adjacent `span` preceding it. So `div` elements that do not have a preceding `span` will not be matched at all.

Comment: I just though of a modification I need to make. It should apply to all but the first column, so my code really should be: $("#myTable td").not(":eq(0)").find("div").width(50); How would I adapt your code in this case?

Comment: @santa: Is the first column for headings? If so, the best solution would be to make them `<th>` elements instead of `<td>`. If that's not the case, then change `td` to `td:not(:first-child)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('span').length>0) console.log('found a span');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$('td span').next().css({width:'50px'})
```

should do the trick.